# Re-Agreeing to public WiFi through login screens

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

On board a train whose WiFi has two screens (click "Join", click "I agree") I have no difficulty from macOS. I'm offered the two screens each time and I click to connect.

But iOS (11.2.6) appears to simplify the login by automating the clicks, after a past initial login. This in turn seems not to go well with this particular WiFi setup.

The WiFi icon indicates that there is a connection, but I can't ping outside.

Tinkering with the settings in the following ways to (re-)establish the connection does not work:

1. Turning WiFi off then on.
2. Forgetting then reselecting the WiFi network.
3. Turning off "auto-join" and "auto-login".
4. Clicking "Renew lease".

None of these make me go through the click-to-join-then-click-to-agree screens.

How do I connect through iOS to this (public, unsecured) network?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your iOS device may have some sort of ban on the network. From experience, you can set suspicious devices to be auto-banned. This is especially common on public networks. I would imagine that iOS tried to Auto-Join too many times and the network may think it is a DDoS attack. I suggest you talk to the transport company on why you aren't connecting to the internet. Of course, this isn't something that just everyone will be looking to talk to a transport company and I understand it's inconvenient, but I've run a network in the past that's public and that's basically how it works.

EDIT: The image shows our set duration of invalid attempts. We have set our network to ban the device for 15 minutes, although there are options to ban the device permanently (strictly that only administrators can unblock the device). These systems may vary, but work similarly.

[image: Image1]

Comment: If I disconnect then reattempt to connect, how would the network determine that it's the same device (either triggered manually or automatically)? That would require sending my mac address, no? In this exchange, there is otherwise no equivalent to saving cookies on my device.

Comment: Yes, the MAC Address is involved. I'll screenshot my network and attach it in just a moment to demonstrate.